# Issue with vertical line (Google chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Folks,

I was trying to create a Column Chart using google chart API and I am having lots of issue in getting Y-AXIS line.

I understand x-axis is string that is why vertical grid line is not coming but Y-axis line must come. I am marking in RED as of now this line is not coming.

[image]

I have following code.

```
function drawChartSecond(resp) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Activity');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');

    data.addRows([
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2 ],
        ['Commute', 2 ],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title : '',
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Activity',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'Black',
                fontSize : '12',
                fontName : 'Arial'
            },
            baselineColor: '#CCCCCC'
        },
        chartArea : {
            left: '8%',
            top: '8%',
            height:'70%',
            width:'100%'
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartdivsecond'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get that baseline is to use a chart with a continuous axis.  You can use a DataView to convert your data to appropriately formatted numbers, and use the `hAxis.ticks` option to re-label the axis tick marks so it looks correct:

```
function drawChartSecond(resp) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Activity');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');
    data.addRows([
        ['Work', 11],
        ['Eat', 2 ],
        ['Commute', 2 ],
        ['Watch TV', 2],
        ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([{
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return {v: row + 1, f: dt.getValue(row, 0)};
        }
    }, 1]);

    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        ticks.push({v: i + 1, f: data.getValue(i, 0)});
    }

    var options = {
        title : '',
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Activity',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'Black',
                fontSize : '12',
                fontName : 'Arial'
            },
            baselineColor: '#CCCCCC',
            ticks: ticks
        },
        chartArea : {
            left: '8%',
            top: '8%',
            height:'70%',
            width:'100%'
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartdivsecond'));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6mXkv/